# Programmer's tale about float and double datatypes

Tags: floating-point, programming-languages, precision, currency

I've heard a story some years ago about how using the *float* datatype (instead of *double* or, even better, *big integers*) broke some stock market company because of precision. The financial results were calculated out of precision and were showing some nice result, but in reality the company(?) was broken. It could be a bank, though.

Does anyone know about this story? If yes, where could I find more details? I cannot remember enough details to do a proper search in the internet.

Comment: Using `double` instead of `float` for currencies merely delays the problem. Some sort of fixed (decimal) point integers should be used. This question sounds very off-topic for this site (not sure if there is a SE site where it would fit better, though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vancouver Stock Exchange

[Index was initialized at 1000 and subsequently updated and truncated to three decimal places on each trade.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vancouver_Stock_Exchange#Rounding_errors_on_its_Index_price)

Comment: So this is not a `float` versus `double` issue or a floating-point issue at all. Wikipedia says the price was calculated and then **truncated** to three decimal places. That produces a rounding error averaging .0005, regardless of whether the underlying arithmetic is floating-point, fixed-point, perfect real mathematics, or voodoo. Doing it 3000 times a day averages 1.5 points per day. 20 business days/month gives 30 points/month, near what the article said, 25/month.